# AngularJS - Controller one a compiled directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

As the name suggests, what is the difference? A controller is suppose to act as a constructor - to instantiate all the variables and/or make API calls.

A directive's controller also runs before the DOM is compiled, and so I am wondering if it could be used for the some context? In other words, are these two codes the same?

Say that I have this markup:

```
<div my-div ng-controller="DivController">
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('DivController', function($scope) {
        $scope.value = 'initialize';
    })
    .directive('myDiv', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // Now use $scope.value
            }
        }
    });

// VS this code

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('myDiv', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.value = 'initialize';
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // Now use $scope.value 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Directive controller role is inter directive communication, and expose an API for the directive. Similar to ngModel and ngModelController. Add to that `ng-controller` creates a new scope.

Comment: You might find the following question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225702/angular-ngcontroller-vs-controller-constructed-within-directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no!!

Yes because:

- both are run pre-compilation
- in this case, they produce the same end results

No because:

- usually a directive doesn't have its own scope, unless instructed otherwise.
- ng-controller has it's own scope and can access its parent scope.
- a directive's controller is shared among all instance of the directive (obviously)
- related directive controllers (directives which "require" another) can communicate

---

This is VERY important because it can produce some weird results. For instance, check this snippet ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tivie/9egr4toc/))

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('myDiv', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.value = 'directive';
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
    };
  }
]);
app.controller('parentCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = 'Parent Controller';
  $scope.parentvalue = 'wow parent value';
});
app.controller('DivController', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = 'controller';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
    <h1>parent scope</h1>
    <br/>parentvalue: <b>{{parentvalue}}</b>
    <br/>value: <b>{{value}}</b>
    <br/>ajaxvalue: <b>{{ajaxvalue}}</b>
    <br/>
    <hr/>
    <div my-div ng-controller="DivController">
      <h1>Controller and directive</h1>
      <br/>parentvalue: <b>{{parentvalue}}</b>
      <br/>value: <b>{{value}}</b>
      <br/>ajaxvalue: <b>{{ajaxvalue}}</b>
      <br/>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div my-div>
      <h1>Directive only</h1>
      parentvalue: <b>{{parentvalue}}</b>
      <br/>value: <b>{{value}}</b>
      <br/>ajaxvalue: <b>{{ajaxvalue}}</b>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As you see the directive overwrite `$scope.value` of it's parent and sibling. However, if you run an async call and change the parent `$scope.value` the value gets replaced in the directive but not in the child directive.

Obviously, you can create an isolated scope for the directive.