# Difference between directive controller and normal controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the difference between a normal `ng-controller` and a `controller` inside a directive.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <directive></directive>
</div>
```

Below i have a `directive` inside `MyCtrl` and my directive also has a `controller` defined.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('map', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function(){}
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {}
```

1. What is the difference between a normal `ng-controller` and a `controller` inside a directive.
2. Why does the `directive` have a `controller` function?.

Comment: there is no difference between those 2... a directive may want to fetch data or do some operations on the model which is done in the controller that is why you have a controller for directive

Comment: This SO may share some light to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19227433/2777098

Comment: I would think, that scope is different. Sure it depends on whether this is an isolated scope or not.

Answer (score 1):

controllers is not a function to apply it is a container of the logic that you will apply on a certain scope this logic will be in different functions declared inside the controller so the real question is not the difference but when to use this and when to use the other.

directives mainly are used for code re-usability and isolating a part of the app from the outside world and its controller is the container that hold all its variables and functions that will be called during the app run time.

from another point of view directive are much more like classes in c++ language as directives can has its own scope and is used mainly for code re-usability.
so actually this question is much more like asking what is the difference between declaring a function in a class or in the main function